# What does it mean for nibBundleOrNil to return the name of the bundle and the message "(not yet loaded)"?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, sdk, unity-game-engine

We've got a controller that is a descendant of UIViewController.  That is, something like:

- UIView Controller
- - BaseViewControllerChild
- - - ViewControllerInQuestion

This ViewControllerInQuestion is not showing up when we try to display it.  We happen to have a log statement in the init method.

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    NSLog(@"ViewControllerInQuestion : initWithNibName:: %@ %@", nibNameOrNil, nibBundleOrNil);
    // ... 
}
```

Our logging there reports something interesting.

```
ViewControllerInQuestion : initWithNibName: ViewControllerInQuestion 
NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/84129-777-IAMSMASHINGNUMBERSBUTYOUGETTHE
IDEA-85327/OurApp.app/OurSDKResourcesBundle.bundle> (not yet loaded)
```

In particular is that last part where we see it say "**(not yet loaded)**".  **What does that mean?**  We've built our resources bundle and it seems to be happily situated in our project.

*Context*

Don't get scared off by the context (you've gone too far!), but we're actually bringing up the view associated with this viewcontroller from our SDK within Unity. That is, we've got an XCode project created by Unity, we've added our own SDK to that XCode project, and this viewcontroller is in that SDK.  It also doesn't show up.

Other questions/search results have mentioned exceptions or different errors.  This one is just from this log statement as we debug why the XIBs won't show up; it's not an exception, it just doesn't display.  What does it mean?

*BONUS NOTE: Our code was playing nice in a later version of Unity (4.1.2).   To make it compile with an older Unity version (3.5.7), we had to modify a lot of project settings on our the XCode project (that Unity spits out) and change the code slightly.  The inner SDK code itself wasn't changed: we only changed the files and project for the XCode project that Unity spits out, which means the problem could be 1.) our project setting / XCode project changes or 2.) something in an older version of Unity or iOS.  The first step is understanding what "(not yet loaded)" means, I'd think!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(not yet loaded)...

`NSBundle` is a container for image, and interface resources but it's also a container for code resources. You can instantiate a bundle without the code resources being loaded and then explicitly load them later (`- isLoaded`, `- load`, `- loadAndReturnError:`).

Ensure that all of the resources are configured to be copied into your bundle during building. You can open the bundle in Finder (right click and show package contents) to verify that it contains everything you expect it to.